# TweenMax won't initialize correctly: "Uncaught Cannot tween a null target."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, gsap

In my app, I'm trying to use the [TweenMax/TimelineMax libraries of GSAP](http://greensock.com/tweenmax) to animate changes, but I'm running into a early error in my code. Simplified (this is a React/Redux app using ES6):

```
import TimelineMax from 'gsap';
import TweenMax from 'gsap';
import GSAP from 'gsap-react-plugin';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

someFunction() {
    var mailboxDropdown = ReactDOM.findDOMNode( this.refs.mailboxDropdown );
    // TweenLite.to(this, 0.1, { "y-offset": '-50px', 'opacity' : 0 });
    console.log(mailboxDropdown)
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    console.log('here');
    tl.to(mailboxDropdown, 0.4, { "y-offset": '-50px' }, 'slideUp' )
    tl.to(mailboxDropdown, 1, { opacity: 0 }, 'slideUp-=.5');
};
```

The errors are weird. Firstly, if I don't initialize TimelineMax with an object -- something like `new TimelineMax({repeat: 1})` -- (although the docs say its default constructor arg is `null`), it throws an error before even hitting the `console.log('here')`.

> Uncaught Cannot tween a null target.

If I **do** initialize it with an object as in the previous sentence, I hit an error when I try to call `tl.to`. Specifically:

> Uncaught TypeError: tl.to is not a function

Even though `to` is **definitely** in the docs. The `tl` object appears to be a `TweenMax` object:

> TweenMax {vars: Object, _totalDuration: 0, _duration: 0, _delay: 0, _timeScale: 1…}

But it isn't responding to most methods, including `add` and a bunch of others.

Any idea what's going on here? It's super confusing to me, cause all the docs/tutorials seem to suggest that what I'm doing is fine, and all the relevant objects (`mailboxDropdown`, etc) seem correctly defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before posting this question (and after much searching around and blind experimentation), I discovered that the issue actually has to do with importing. I'm not sure **why**, but removing the `TimelineMax` import fixed things, so that everything in the original code worked just fine. That is, my imports should have been this:

```
import TweenMax from 'gsap';
import GSAP from 'gsap-react-plugin';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Not this:

```
import TimelineMax from 'gsap';
import TweenMax from 'gsap';
import GSAP from 'gsap-react-plugin';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Some sort of namespace clash/overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

import TimelineMax from 'gsap/TimelineMax';
That's works

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Greensock NPM docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/greensock#npm), you can specify individual exports using the bracketed notation:

```
import {TimelineMax, TweenMax} from 'gsap'
```

Answer (score 0):

NPM module is not submitted properly yet. Use

```
import TimelineMax from 'gsap/TimelineMax'
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error:

```
Uncaught Cannot tween a null target.
```

By importing this way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import TweenMax, {Power4} from 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax';
import EasePack from 'gsap/src/uncompressed/easing/EasePack';
import TimelineMax from 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineMax';
```